What are the known properties of karma?
I asked if there is a way to measure karma ( Is there a way to measure (bad) karma? ) but this was too much to hope for.
So now I will start with asking for the known properties of karma, to gain a better understanding.

Karma is action. That which causes action is the gunas. Consequently the properties of actions (or karma) are the qualities of the gunas, of which there are three, satva (goodness), raja (passion) and tamas (negativity).
Karma, or action, brings results, or phala. For each type of karma there is a corresponding result. Each type of karma is tainted by the gunas. This means the results (more karma) too carry that same taint, or property.
For examaple a good action results in good results. That's one property. An example may be a simple smile, which results in a smile in return.
A passionate action, will result in passionate results. Any enthusiastic action you take hoping for a result will most likely be rajas.
A negative action will bring negative fruit. Hurting other beings may well result in being hurt later, for example. An eye for an eye.
In chapter 14 of the Bhagavad Gita, Sri Krishna explains the gunas.
Keep in mind that one always acts, so karma is incessant and the jiva is bound by its results. Actions are countless and the results too. Hence we cannot count them or clearly know them. Ask yourself how many action you took last week. This is a property of karma, it is without a known beginning or end.

I did not know about the difference of guna and karma, and I am still unsure if I understand this the right way. Stubborn westerners, like me, subsume all that by the word "karma". We live and learn.

As it is a complex and difficult question (obviously, I do not even have a concept about the words to ask yet) I will wait for more answers or comments before accepting an answer.

You said: "For each type of karma  ..." and that is exactly what I am asking for: what types of karma are there, how can they be distinguished or classified? Or, the types of guna?

Karma means action.  Karma properties are good, passionate and bad. These are the three main types. They may very, an action can be both passionate and good, or pasionate and bad.

It is the underlying intention, not the result that makes an action good, passionate or bad.
